# Ignore field on read (deserialization) with C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document with two fields; `name` and `documents`.

I want both fields to be serialized and inserted into my collection during writing. BUT, I do not want `documents` to be deserialized during reading (I am happy with this field being null),

Here is the entity class:

```
public class EmployeeDocument
{
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("documents")]
    public List<string> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible to ignore a property for deserialization, but not for serialization. 
And i think it's not the best approach.
If you want to read not all properties from the document, you could exclude them on projection, if you than want to have the same `EmployeeDocument` class, you could deserialize your `BsonDocument` to it, i mean something like:

```
var emps = db.GetCollection<EmployeeDocument>("empl");
var employees =emps.Find(x=>true)
             .Project(Builders<EmployeeDocument>.Projection.Exclude(x=>x.Documents))
             .ToList()
             .Select(x=>BsonSerializer.Deserialize<EmployeeDocument>(x));
```